# Looping through the content of a file in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, loops, unix, io

How do I iterate through each line of a text file with [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))?

With this script:

```
echo "Start!"
for p in (peptides.txt)
do
    echo "${p}"
done
```

I get this output on the screen:

```
Start!
./runPep.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./runPep.sh: line 3: `for p in (peptides.txt)'
```

(Later I want to do something more complicated with `$p` than just output to the screen.)

---

The environment variable **SHELL** is (from env):

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

`/bin/bash --version` output:

```
GNU bash, version 3.1.17(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

`cat /proc/version` output:

```
Linux version 2.6.18.2-34-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (SUSE Linux)) #1 SMP Mon Nov 27 11:46:27 UTC 2006
```

The file peptides.txt contains:

```
RKEKNVQ
IPKKLLQK
QYFHQLEKMNVK
IPKKLLQK
GDLSTALEVAIDCYEK
QYFHQLEKMNVKIPENIYR
RKEKNVQ
VLAKHGKLQDAIN
ILGFMK
LEDVALQILL
```

Comment: Oh, I see many things have happened here: all the comments were deleted and  the question being reopened. Just for reference, the accepted answer in [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/1983854) addresses the problem in a canonical way and should be preferred over the accepted one here.

Comment: for `$IFS` see [What is the exact meaning of `IFS=$'\n'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128235/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-ifs-n/66942306#66942306)

Comment: don't use bash use `awk` https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

Answer (score 2934, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
while read p; do
  echo "$p"
done <peptides.txt
```

As pointed out in the comments, this has the side effects of trimming leading whitespace, interpreting backslash sequences, and skipping the last line if it's missing a terminating linefeed. If these are concerns, you can do:

```
while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]
do
  printf '%s\n' "$p"
done < peptides.txt
```

---

Exceptionally, if the [loop body may read from standard input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107800/using-while-loop-to-ssh-to-multiple-servers), you can open the file using a different file descriptor:

```
while read -u 10 p; do
  ...
done 10<peptides.txt
```

Here, 10 is just an arbitrary number (different from 0, 1, 2).

Comment: How should I interpret the last line? File peptides.txt is redirected to standard input and somehow to the whole of the while block?

Comment: "Slurp peptides.txt into this while loop, so the 'read' command has something to consume."  My "cat" method is similar, sending the output of a command into the while block for consumption by 'read', too, only it launches another program to get the work done.

Comment: This didn't work for me. The second ranked answer, which used cat and a pipe, did work for me.

Comment: This method seems to skip the last line of a file.

Comment: Can this be done in reverse starting at the bottom of the file?

Comment: @Dss Then I would use a solution based on `cat` but replace `cat` by `tac`.

Comment: @BrunoDeFraine I've tried that but tac seems to make each space a new line. I need the full line delimited by the newline char. maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: @BrunoDeFraine Ok I found this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7012 ..change cat to tac and it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Dss I meant the solution from Warren Young http://stackoverflow.com/a/1521470/6918 ; just replace cat by tac and you should read the lines in reverse.

Comment: Double quote the lines !! echo "$p"  and the file.. trust me it will bite you if you don't!!! I KNOW!  lol

Comment: Both versions fail to read a final line if it is not terminated with a newline. **Always** use `while read p || [[ -n $p ]]; do ...`

Comment: This does not work for lines that end with a backslash "\". Lines ending with a backslash will be prepended to the next line (and the \ will be removed).

Comment: @Veda Now that's weird. What I would expect is, you get an extra `n` after the backslash, and the lines get concatenated. Because that would mean, the backslash escapes the backslash of `\n`, causing it to be interpreted literally rather than as a newline. But the fact that the backslash disappears, as well as the newline, means it's consumed for some kind of escaping like expected, but gets merged with the original newline character into something that isn't printed... Do you have a tool that displays unprinted characters in some way? Would interest me what that results in.

Comment: @EgorHans the \ escapes the "\n" character which is a single character. Google for an "ascii table". Character 10 is \n and character 13 is \r. Linux "xxd" tool will show you the characters. A file with `a\na\n\\n` will look like: `610a 610a 5c0a` (0a is hex for 10, so \n). So the last case the "5c" character or the "\" is escaping a single character.

Comment: @Veda Ah OK, now I understand better. Didn't realize the file content gets dumped into the execution flow the way it's inside the file, where of course `\n` is one single character. For some reason I've been thinking it gets backresolved to the control sequence while processed. Still, it's somewhat weird that an escaped `\n` is something without a printed representation. One would expect it to resolve to the char sequence "\n" when escaped.

Comment: Your soul be blessed for that different file descriptor command, made me happy, wasted 8 days on an error generated by standard input replacement. +1

Comment: can you please mention what the `-r` flag does?

Comment: @AlexanderMills `-r` disables the interpretation of backslashes as escape sequences. The empty `IFS` disables that `read` splits up the line in fields. And because `read` fails when it encounters end-of-file before the line ends, we also test for a non-empty line.

Comment: `read` is ignoring the `\r` character when the file uses windows line endings (i.e. `\r\n`). How can I make `read` treat `\r` as part of the newline sequence?

Comment: If you are like me and you do these things in the shell in a single line, you need to add another semi-colon like so:    

while read p; do echo "$p"; done <peptides.txt

Comment: Reading through the other answers, I think this is probably the most idiomatic way of doing this

Answer (score 782):

```
cat peptides.txt | while read line 
do
   # do something with $line here
done
```

and the one-liner variant:

```
cat peptides.txt | while read line; do something_with_$line_here; done
```

These options will skip the last line of the file if there is no trailing line feed.

You can avoid this by the following:

```
cat peptides.txt | while read line || [[ -n $line ]];
do
   # do something with $line here
done
```

Comment: In general, if you're using "cat" with only one argument, you're doing something wrong (or suboptimal).

Comment: Yes, it's just not as efficient as Bruno's, because it launches another program, unnecessarily.  If efficiency matters, do it Bruno's way.  I remember my way because you can use it with other commands, where the "redirect in from" syntax doesn't work.

Comment: There's another, more serious problem with this: because the while loop is part of a pipeline, it runs in a subshell, and hence any variables set inside the loop are lost when it exits (see http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/mirroring/bashfaq/024). This can be very annoying (depending on what you're trying to do in the loop).

Comment: @JesperE would you care to elaborate with an alternative example?

Comment: @Ogre: He means you should be doing it like Bruno did in his accepted answer. Both work. Bruno's way is just a bit more efficient, since it doesn't run an external command to do the file reading bit. If the efficiency matters, do it Bruno's way. If not, then do it whatever way makes the most sense to you.

Comment: @OgrePsalm33: Warren is right. The "cat" command is used for concatenating files. If you are not concatenating files, chances are that you don't need to use "cat".

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  I wanted to make a point of it because I see a lot of overused examples in scripts and such, where "cat" simply serves as an extra step to get the contents of a single file.

Comment: I use "cat file | " as the start of a lot of my commands purely because I often prototype with "head file |"

Comment: @matkelcey Also, how else would you put an entire file into the front of a pipeline?  Bash gives you here strings, which are awesome (especially for things like `if grep -q 'findme' <<< "$var"`) but not portable, and I wouldn't want to start a large pipeline with one.  Something like `cat ifconfig.output | grep inet[^6] | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d':' -f2` is easier to read, since everything follows from left to right.  It's like strtoking with `awk` instead of `cut` because you don't want empty tokens - it's sort of an abuse of the command, but that's just how it's done.

Comment: This may be not that efficient, but it's much more readable than other answers.

Comment: +1 for readability, and also modularity - this code can easily be put into a more complex pipeline by replacing 'cat ...' with output of something else.

Comment: It is much better resolve than Bruno has written. It is specially usefull when data is created dynamically by command. Using Bruno's solution, loop will receive any data after command will completly done. Your solution gives command result on line into loop, without taking buffer from system. for example replace 'cat peptides.txt' by 'find /', or in previous solution 'done <peptides.txt' by 'done < $(find /)' . it can fail execution because there is a chance for overflow buffer or consume all memory.

Comment: By the time you care about the difference in performance you won't be asking SO these sorts of questions.

Comment: This is, however, great for grep, sed, or any other text manipulation prepending the read.

Comment: this does not work if any of the commands inside your loop run commands via ssh; the stdin stream gets consumed (even if ssh is not using it), and the loop terminates after the first iteration.

Comment: As in the accepted answer, this will have unpleasant surprises without `read -r` in some corner cases. Basically always use `read -r` unless you specifically require the quirky behavior of plain legacy `read`.

Comment: It skips the last line. So as workaround, must add empty line at the last.

Comment: @januarvs: It only does that if the last line of your file has no LF terminator, which will cause lots of other things to fail, too.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Your link is broken, the new one is : https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: This is [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat).

Comment: I like this approach more because it is easier to understand and you can easily replace `cat` part with anything that generates stdout output.

Comment: Please add more line breaks in the code, especially just before `while`!

Answer (score 247):

**Option 1a:** While loop:  Single line at a time:  Input redirection

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='peptides.txt'
echo Start
while read p; do 
    echo "$p"
done < "$filename"
```

**Option 1b:** While loop:  Single line at a time:
Open the file, read from a file descriptor (in this case file descriptor #4).

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='peptides.txt'
exec 4<"$filename"
echo Start
while read -u4 p ; do
    echo "$p"
done
```

**Note: Option 2 was removed. Ignore comments referring to Option 2 as it was rightly removed as an anti-pattern (see edits if you really need to know)**

Comment: For option 1b: does the file descriptor need to be closed again? E.g. the loop could be an inner loop.

Comment: The file descriptor will be cleaned up with the process exits.  An explicit close can be done to reuse the fd number.  To close a fd, use another exec with the &- syntax, like this:
    exec 4<&-

Comment: Thank you for Option 2. I ran into huge problems with Option 1 because I needed to read from stdin within the loop; in such a case Option 1 will not work.

Comment: You should point out more clearly that Option 2 is [strongly discouraged](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).
@masgo Option 1b should work in that case, and can be combined with the input redirection syntax from Option 1a by replacing `done < $filename` with `done 4<$filename` (which is useful if you want to read the file name from a command parameter, in which case you can just replace `$filename` by `$1`).

Comment: I need to loop over file contents such as `tail -n +2 myfile.txt | grep 'somepattern' | cut -f3`, while running ssh commands inside the loop (consumes stdin); option 2 here appears to be the only way?

Comment: Option 2 seems to be the best when some actions should be performed on remote host via SSH.

Comment: 1a for me is fine as soon as One add "echo $p" at end (last line from file)

Comment: upvoted for showing the example of a filename as a variable. Thanks!

Comment: if you don't like magic numbers and do not fetishize short variable names, you can use (\n is a new line, cannot format a comment) ```
    someFile_DescriptorNum=4\n
    eval "exec ${someFile_DescriptorNum}<${someFile_Path}"\n
    while read -u${someFile_DescriptorNum} eachLine ; do\n
        echo "${eachLine}";\n
    done\n
```

Answer (score 156):

This is no better than other answers, but is one more way to get the job done in a file without spaces (see comments). I find that I often need one-liners to dig through lists in text files without the extra step of using separate script files.

```
for word in $(cat peptides.txt); do echo $word; done
```

This format allows me to put it all in one command-line. Change the "echo $word" portion to whatever you want and you can issue multiple commands separated by semicolons. The following example uses the file's contents as arguments into two other scripts you may have written.

```
for word in $(cat peptides.txt); do cmd_a.sh $word; cmd_b.py $word; done
```

Or if you intend to use this like a stream editor (learn sed) you can dump the output to another file as follows.

```
for word in $(cat peptides.txt); do cmd_a.sh $word; cmd_b.py $word; done > outfile.txt
```

I've used these as written above because I have used text files where I've created them with one word per line. (See comments) If you have spaces that you don't want splitting your words/lines, it gets a little uglier, but the same command still works as follows:

```
OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; for line in $(cat peptides.txt); do cmd_a.sh $line; cmd_b.py $line; done > outfile.txt; IFS=$OLDIFS
```

This just tells the shell to split on newlines only, not spaces, then returns the environment back to what it was previously. At this point, you may want to consider putting it all into a shell script rather than squeezing it all into a single line, though.

Best of luck!

Comment: This doesn't meet the requirement (iterate through each line) if the file contains spaces or tabs, but can be useful if you want to iterate through each field in a tab/space separated file.

Comment: The bash $(<peptides.txt) is perhaps more elegant, but it's still wrong, what Joao said correct, you are performing command substitution logic where space or newline is the same thing.  If a line has a space in it, the loop executes TWICE or more for that one line.  So your code should properly read: for word in $(<peptides.txt); do ....  If you know for a fact there are no spaces, then a line equals a word and you're okay.

Comment: @JoaoCosta,maxpolk : Good points that I hadn't considered. I've edited the original post to reflect them. Thanks!

Comment: Using `for` makes the input tokens/lines subject to shell expansions, which is usually undesirable; try this: `for l in $(echo '* b c'); do echo "[$l]"; done` - as you'll see, the `*` - even though originally a *quoted* literal - expands to the files in the current directory.

Comment: Joao and maxpolk, you are addressing the issue I'm having, but I'm still getting a separate iteration for each half of each line with a space:

> cat linkedin_OSInt.txt 
https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/f?type=all&keywords="foo bar"
https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/f?type=all&keywords="baz bux"

> for url in $(<linkedin_OSInt.txt); do echo "$url"; done
https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/f?type=all&keywords="foo
bar"
https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/f?type=all&keywords="baz
bux"

I'll try the other approaches here, but would like understand why this one doesn't work.

Comment: @dblanchard: The last example, using $IFS, should ignore spaces. Have you tried that version?

Comment: please notice for changing cat peptides.txt by find /  . for loop will not start before internal cat finishes. between these steps it is possible buffer overflow.

Comment: The way how this command gets a lot more complex as crucial issues are fixed, presents very well why using `for` to iterate file lines is a a bad idea. Plus, the expansion aspect mentioned by @mklement0 (even though that probably can be circumvented by bringing in escaped quotes, which again makes things more complex and less readable).

Comment: This is, in a readable way, the only answer that also reads the latest line of a file, which is a pro.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I need. The other answers that use while to iterate over lines or ok when one wants to deal with lines of text. But I'd use Python for that. In a shell I often have files containing hundreds of items that will be treated as tokens. I need the removal of newlines, which this syntax provides. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No need in OLDIFS if use subshell-parentheses () around `IFS=$'\n'; for ...; done`

Answer (score 117):

A few more things not covered by other answers:

## Reading from a delimited file

```
# ':' is the delimiter here, and there are three fields on each line in the file
# IFS set below is restricted to the context of `read`, it doesn't affect any other code
while IFS=: read -r field1 field2 field3; do
  # process the fields
  # if the line has less than three fields, the missing fields will be set to an empty string
  # if the line has more than three fields, `field3` will get all the values, including the third field plus the delimiter(s)
done < input.txt
```

## Reading from the output of another command, using process substitution

```
while read -r line; do
  # process the line
done < <(command ...)
```

This approach is better than `command ... | while read -r line; do ...` because the while loop here runs in the current shell rather than a subshell as in the case of the latter. See the related post [A variable modified inside a while loop is not remembered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered).

## Reading from a null delimited input, for example `find ... -print0`

```
while read -r -d '' line; do
  # logic
  # use a second 'read ... <<< "$line"' if we need to tokenize the line
done < <(find /path/to/dir -print0)
```

Related read: [BashFAQ/020 - How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)

## Reading from more than one file at a time

```
while read -u 3 -r line1 && read -u 4 -r line2; do
  # process the lines
  # note that the loop will end when we reach EOF on either of the files, because of the `&&`
done 3< input1.txt 4< input2.txt
```

Based on [@chepner's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16649390/6862601):

`-u` is a bash extension. For POSIX compatibility, each call would look something like `read -r X <&3`.

## Reading a whole file into an array (Bash versions earlier to 4)

```
while read -r line; do
    my_array+=("$line")
done < my_file
```

If the file ends with an incomplete line (newline missing at the end), then:

```
while read -r line || [[ $line ]]; do
    my_array+=("$line")
done < my_file
```

## Reading a whole file into an array (Bash versions 4x and later)

```
readarray -t my_array < my_file
```

or

```
mapfile -t my_array < my_file
```

And then

```
for line in "${my_array[@]}"; do
  # process the lines
done
```

- [More about the shell builtins `read` and `readarray` commands - GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read)
- [More about `IFS` - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator)
- [BashFAQ/001 - How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005#Loading_lines_from_a_file_or_stream)

Related posts:

- [Creating an array from a text file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30988586/6862601)
- [What is the difference between thee approaches to reading a file that has just one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51937702/6862601)
- [Bash while read loop extremely slow compared to cat, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13762625/6862601)

Comment: note that instead of `command < input_filename.txt` you can always do `input_generating_command | command` or `command < <(input_generating_command)`

Comment: Thanks for reading file into array. Exactly what I need, because I need each line to parse twice, add to new variables, do some validations etc.

Comment: this is by far the most useful version I think

Comment: 'read -r -d ''` works for null delimited input in combination with `while`, not standalone (`read -r d '' foo bar`). See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693090/splitting-a-null-separated-string).

Comment: the `array+=("$item")` syntax wasn't added until Bash 3.1; prior to then you needed  `array[index++]=$item` (after you'd first set `((index=${#array[@]}))`). Note that although `array=("${array[@]}" "$item")` does work, each such assignment takes  time proportional to the size of the array, so doing it in a loop gets very expensive.

Answer (score 54):

Use a while loop, like this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   echo "$line"
done <file
```

Notes:

1. If you don't set the `IFS` properly, you will lose indentation.
2. [You should almost always use the -r option with read.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
3. [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The -r option prevents backslash interpretation. `Note #2` is a link where it is described in detail...

Comment: Combine this with the "read -u" option in another answer and then it's perfect.

Comment: @FlorinAndrei : The above example doesn't need the `-u` option, are you talking about another example with `-u`?

Comment: Looked through your links, and was surprised there's no answer that simply links your link in Note 2. That page provides everything you need to know about that subject. Or are link-only answers discouraged or something?

Comment: @EgorHans : link only answers are generally deleted.

Comment: Ah. Alright, never suggesting a link-only answer again. Maybe there even were some, we'll never know.

Answer (score 19):

If you don't want your read to be broken by newline character, use -

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "$line"
done < "$1"
```

Then run the script with file name as parameter.

Comment: Note to self: the '-r' option 'prevents backslash interpretation'; http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 17):

Suppose you have this file:

```
$ cat /tmp/test.txt
Line 1
    Line 2 has leading space
Line 3 followed by blank line

Line 5 (follows a blank line) and has trailing space    
Line 6 has no ending CR
```

There are four elements that will alter the meaning of the file output read by many Bash solutions:

1. The blank line 4;
2. Leading or trailing spaces on two lines;
3. Maintaining the meaning of individual lines (i.e., each line is a record);
4. The line 6 not terminated with a CR.

If you want the text file line by line including blank lines and terminating lines without CR, you must use a while loop and you must have an alternate test for the final line.

Here are the methods that may change the file (in comparison to what `cat` returns):

1) Lose the last line and leading and trailing spaces:

```
$ while read -r p; do printf "%s\n" "'$p'"; done </tmp/test.txt
'Line 1'
'Line 2 has leading space'
'Line 3 followed by blank line'
''
'Line 5 (follows a blank line) and has trailing space'
```

(If you do `while IFS= read -r p; do printf "%s\n" "'$p'"; done </tmp/test.txt` instead, you preserve the leading and trailing spaces but still lose the last line if it is not terminated with CR)

2) Using process substitution with `cat` will reads the entire file in one gulp and loses the meaning of individual lines:

```
$ for p in "$(cat /tmp/test.txt)"; do printf "%s\n" "'$p'"; done
'Line 1
    Line 2 has leading space
Line 3 followed by blank line

Line 5 (follows a blank line) and has trailing space    
Line 6 has no ending CR'
```

(If you remove the `"` from `$(cat /tmp/test.txt)` you read the file word by word rather than one gulp. Also probably not what is intended...)

---

The most robust and simplest way to read a file line-by-line and preserve all spacing is:

```
$ while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do printf "'%s'\n" "$line"; done </tmp/test.txt
'Line 1'
'    Line 2 has leading space'
'Line 3 followed by blank line'
''
'Line 5 (follows a blank line) and has trailing space    '
'Line 6 has no ending CR'
```

If you want to strip leading and trading spaces, remove the `IFS=` part:

```
$ while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do printf "'%s'\n" "$line"; done </tmp/test.txt
'Line 1'
'Line 2 has leading space'
'Line 3 followed by blank line'
''
'Line 5 (follows a blank line) and has trailing space'
'Line 6 has no ending CR'
```

(A text file without a terminating `\n`, while fairly common, is considered broken under POSIX. If you can count on the trailing `\n` you do not need `|| [[ -n $line ]]` in the `while` loop.)

More at the [BASH FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 12):

I like to use `xargs` instead of `while`. `xargs` is powerful and command line friendly

`cat peptides.txt | xargs -I % sh -c "echo %"`

With `xargs`, you can also add verbosity with `-t` and validation with `-p`

Comment: There are serious security problems with this approach. What if your `peptides.txt` contains something that unescapes to `$(rm -rf ~)`, or even worse, `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'`?

Answer (score 12):

This might be the simplest answer and maybe it don't work in all cases, but it is working great for me:

```
while read line;do echo "$line";done<peptides.txt
```

if you need to enclose in parenthesis for spaces:

```
while read line;do echo \"$line\";done<peptides.txt
```

Ahhh this is pretty much the same as the answer that got upvoted most, but its all on one line.

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Change the file name from "test" to desired input file 
# (The comments in bash are prefixed with #'s)
for x in $(cat test.txt)
do
    echo $x
done
```

Comment: This answer needs the caveats mentioned in [mightypile's answer](/q/1521462/#19182518), and it can fail badly if any line contains shell metacharacters (due to the unquoted "$x").

Comment: I'm actually surprised people didn't yet come up with the usual [Don't read lines with for](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)...

Comment: This really doesn't work in any general way. Bash splits each line on spaces which is very unlikely a desired outcome.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my real life example how to loop lines of another program output, check for substrings, drop double quotes from variable, use that variable outside of the loop. I guess quite many is asking these questions sooner or later.

```
##Parse FPS from first video stream, drop quotes from fps variable
## streams.stream.0.codec_type="video"
## streams.stream.0.r_frame_rate="24000/1001"
## streams.stream.0.avg_frame_rate="24000/1001"
FPS=unknown
while read -r line; do
  if [[ $FPS == "unknown" ]] && [[ $line == *".codec_type=\"video\""* ]]; then
    echo ParseFPS $line
    FPS=parse
  fi
  if [[ $FPS == "parse" ]] && [[ $line == *".r_frame_rate="* ]]; then
    echo ParseFPS $line
    FPS=${line##*=}
    FPS="${FPS%\"}"
    FPS="${FPS#\"}"
  fi
done <<< "$(ffprobe -v quiet -print_format flat -show_format -show_streams -i "$input")"
if [ "$FPS" == "unknown" ] || [ "$FPS" == "parse" ]; then 
  echo ParseFPS Unknown frame rate
fi
echo Found $FPS
```

Declare variable outside of the loop, set value and use it outside of loop requires *done <<< "$(...)"* syntax. Application need to be run within a context of current console. Quotes around the command keeps newlines of output stream.

Loop match for substrings then reads *name=value* pair, splits right-side part of last *=* character, drops first quote, drops last quote, we have a clean value to be used elsewhere.

Comment: While the answer is correct, I do understand how it ended up down here. The essential method is the same as proposed by many other answers. Plus, it completely drowns in your FPS example.

Comment: This answer is also an example of "quoting done backwards". People put `"literals in quotes"`, while leaving `$expansions` unquoted, because that's how it works in other languages. But it's exactly the reverse of what one should write in Shell.

Answer (score 1):

This is coming rather very late, but with the thought that it may help someone, i am adding the answer. Also this may not be the best way. `head` command can be used with `-n` argument to read ***n lines*** from start of file and likewise `tail` command can be used to read from bottom. Now, to fetch *nth* line from file, we head *n lines*, pipe the data to tail only 1 line from the piped data.

```
   TOTAL_LINES=`wc -l $USER_FILE | cut -d " " -f1 `
   echo $TOTAL_LINES       # To validate total lines in the file

   for (( i=1 ; i <= $TOTAL_LINES; i++ ))
   do
      LINE=`head -n$i $USER_FILE | tail -n1`
      echo $LINE
   done
```

Comment: **Don't do this.** Looping over line numbers and fetching each individual line by way of `sed` or `head` + `tail` is **incredibly** inefficient, and of course begs the question why you don't simply use one of the other solutions here. If you need to know the line number, add a counter to your `while read -r` loop, or use `nl -ba` to add a line number prefix to each line before the loop.

Comment: See also now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538947/counting-lines-or-enumerating-line-numbers-so-i-can-loop-over-them-why-is-this

Comment: @tripleee i have clearly mentioned "this may not be the best way". I have not limited the discussion to "the best or the most efficient solution".

Comment: Iterating over the lines of a file with a for loop can be useful in some situations. For example some commands can make a while loop break. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64049584/2761700

Comment: @tripleee `read` itself is *already* ridiculously slow. In scenarios with very long lines, this solution can likely be faster, so your performance argument doesn't necessarily count. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762625

Comment: @phil294 Reading and discarding the same data over and over is O(n^2) which will be slower than the O(n) `read` in a loop in pretty much all scenarios where it matters at all. The linked question from my second comment has more details.

Comment: There are obvious performance issues, but if you know you only want one line, _not_ near the top of the file, then it's not such a crazy idea. However I would use `head -n $((end_line)) | tail -n $((end_line - start_line + 1 )) | while IFS= read -r ...`. Or for just one line, I might use `sed "1,$((line-1))d;q"`

Answer (score 0):

@Peter: This could work out for you-

```
echo "Start!";for p in $(cat ./pep); do
echo $p
done
```

This would return the output-

```
Start!
RKEKNVQ
IPKKLLQK
QYFHQLEKMNVK
IPKKLLQK
GDLSTALEVAIDCYEK
QYFHQLEKMNVKIPENIYR
RKEKNVQ
VLAKHGKLQDAIN
ILGFMK
LEDVALQILL
```

Comment: This is very bad! [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: This answer is defeating all the principles set by the good answers above!

Comment: Please delete this answer.

Comment: Now guys, don't exaggerate. The answer is bad, but it seems to work, at least for simple use cases. As long as that's provided, being a bad answer doesn't take away the answer's right to exist.

Comment: @EgorHans, I disagree strongly: The point of answers is to teach people how to write software. Teaching people to do things in a way that you *know* is harmful to them and the people who use their software (introducing bugs / unexpected behaviors / etc) is knowingly harming others. An answer known to be harmful has no "right to exist" in a well-curated teaching resource (and curating it is exactly what we, the folks who are voting and flagging, are supposed to be doing here).

Comment: @EgorHans, ...incidentally, the worst data-loss incident I've been personally witness to was caused by ops staff doing something that "seemed to work" in a script (using an unquoted expansion for a filename to be deleted -- when that name was supposed to be able to contain only hex digits). Except a bug in a different piece of software wrote a name with random contents, which had a whitespace-surrounded `*`, and a massive trove of billing-data backups was lost.

Comment: This will work in some cases, but proposed solution is far from good.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go about using xargs

```
cat <file_name> | xargs -I {} echo {}
```

echo can be replaced with other commands or piped further.

Comment: does not work at all, file is big, echo's nothing

Comment: This works in ZSH and is the cleanest way of doing this, although in bash the command is`cat file_name | xargs -I {} echo {}`

Comment: Please remove the first `|` to make it so it works in non-Zsh shells

Comment: The `echo {}` is pointless, since that is the default action for `xargs`

Answer (score -2):

for p in `cat peptides.txt`
do
echo "${p}"
done

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)